# How can I make constructor take a non-const object?

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion

I always get lost when it comes to const types in C++ and my problem is essentially with these.

I've got a following situation: I've got a class Matrix being essentially a two dimensional linked list (a ring with sentinels) and an iterator-like class that can select a row (method of selecting a row) and then go through it (operator++). To obtain that, the iterator stores 3 pointers: the main sentinel, the sentinel of selected sublist (row) and a currently selected node (let's name it caret). If operator++ hits sublist sentinel - then the end of a row is reached, if row selection hits main sentinel, then we've reached the end of a matrix.

Now, since the list is singly-linked and I want my iterator to provide a deleting functionality, I've decided to store `Node**` type for my current node field in iterator. But this yields some problems with constructors.

I've decided to allow for just two types of constructors - one taking Matrix and one taking other iterator. And here is  my issue. The initial state of an iterator created from a matrix has all of its pointers at the same point - main sentinel. Now, it seems from what g++ tells me that my constructor taking `Matrix` must take the type `const Matrix&`. But if so, I cannot assign for my for my caret (being `Node**`) the pointer to Matrix's own pointer since it would be const while caret cannot be const.

How could I possibly work this out? Why constructor cannot take non-const entity? Can I convert within constructor my Matrix from const to non-const? Thanks in advance for any hint on that.

Comment: Why don't you show us the relevant parts of your code? I think it would make the question easier to understand.

Comment: Your Matrix class should provide iterators and const iterators for your copy constructor to work with them. If you provide the relevant code, we could give you some ideas.

Comment: A copy constructor should just do, what its name says, it copies something (of the same type) without wreaking havoc on source objects. Whether you have overloads for Matrix, Matrix&, const Matrix& is merely about ambiguity and performance. I guess, you could run into trouble with all these pointers, because it seems, that your iterator can be used to modify a matrix, which was constructed from it before. So you need to copy actual data for strict ownership of resources or some other approaches for what you want - let's call it submatrices. So yes, you should show us some code.

Answer (score 1):

You must separate Matrix and iterator, so that just iterating does not change Matrix in any way, and any data needed by iteration is stored in iterator class.

Further, if you need iterator to operate on a const Matrix object, you need to provide also a const iterator, which can then have const reference/pointer to the Matrix. But in copy constructor you don't necessarily need this, you can just access fields directly, it is same class after all.

To give iterator classes access to innards of Matrix, you can use friend keyword, or (preferably) you can make iterator classes inner classes of Matrix.